# Add decimal hours to timespan

Tags: c#, .net, .net-3.5, timespan

I have a `Decimal` value representing fractional number of hours in a time interval.

Now I need to sum this value to a `TimeSpan`, but I cannot find an effective method to do it.

My solution, for now, is to do something like this:

```
myTimeSpan + new TimeSpan(0, 0, Math.Abs(decimalHours * 3600))
```

Is there any better way to solve my issue?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

how about

```
myTimeSPan + TimeSpan.FromHours((double)decimalHours);
```